# In Jekyll How Do I Work With a Specific Post?

Tags: jekyll

I have a sidebar in my site that I want to be able to highlight a specific post.

How do I work with a specific post?

I tried this:

```
{% assign workingPost = site.posts.2014-09-08-We-Convert-All-Dollars-to-Bitcoin %}
<div>{{workingPost.title}}</div>
```

But the title is blank. The title for that post is `We Convert All Dollars to Bitcoin` and that was what I expected to get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this for all pages with :

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    {% for p in site.pages %}
        <li{% if p.url == page.url %} class="active"{% endif %}>
            <a href="{{ site.baseurl }}{{ p.url }}">{{ p.title }}</a>
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Note: in your answer, you for loop may collides with **page** variable if you do this in **post** or **page** page.
That's why I use `{% for p in site.pages %}` instead of `{% for page in site.pages %}`

Answer (score 0):

In this [blog post](http://pixelcog.com/blog/2013/jekyll-from-scratch-core-architecture/) a commentator is looping over the collection and comparing titles. Seems lame, but works for now.

```
{% for page in site.pages %}
{% if page.title == 'About' %}
{{ page.content }}
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```